# Is there a help guide to customizing the theme.css style sheet?

Tags: codenameone

I am looking to change the Selected and Pressed colors of the SideCommand commands in theme.css. I know the old Designer had a way to change Selected and Pressed, but I cannot find any hints for these customizations when searching the internet. It seems to me that there are many elements built into the libraries, but I have not seen any examples except for the usual suspects that are set with setUIID. The examples of other customizations have worked beautifully when I have added them. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the developer guide there's a sample for that with buttons which will work just the same for SideCommand:

```css
Button {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1pt solid gray;
    background-color: transparent;
}

Button.pressed {
    background-color: gray;
}
```

There are 4 states you can pick explicitly :

- `.pressed`
- `.selected`
- `.unselected`
- `.disabled`